# Não consigo reduzir o valor do span do html

Tags: javascript, html

Estou fazendo um jogo de adivinhação com um número de tentativas igual a 3. Sempre que o usuário erra o chute, o número de tentativas deve cair, mas isso não está acontecendo. Alguém sabe o que estou errando ??

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Adivinhador</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Adivinhador</h1>
    <form name="adivinha" id="adivinha_form" action="#">
        <p>
            Seu chute: <br>
            <input type="text" id="chute" name="chute">
        </p>

        <button onclick="valida()" reset="true">Arriscar</button>

        <p>Tentativas: <span id="tentativa">3</span> </p>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="adivinhacao.js"></script> <!-- Para converter valor de span no JS, chamar o innerText -->
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
var chute = document.getElementById("chute")
var tentativa = document.getElementById("tentativa")

function valida() {

    var chute2 = parseInt(chute.value)
    var tentativa2 = parseInt(tentativa.innerText)
    var numero = parseInt(1 + Math.random() * 10)
    if(chute2 >= 0 && chute2 <= 10) {
        aleatorio(numero, chute2, tentativa2)
    }
    else {
        alert("Favor digitar um numero de 0 a 10")
    }
}

function aleatorio(numero, chute2, tentativa2) {
    if (chute2 != numero) {
        alert("Você errou! Tente de novo")
        document.getElementById("adivinha_form").reset();
    }
    else if (chute2 != numero && tentativa2 == 2) {
        alert("Suas chances acabaram! O número correto é " + numero)
    }
    else if (chute2 == numero) {
        alert("Parabéns! Você acertou")
    }
}
```

Comment: voce nao esta mandando atualizar o `tentativa`

Comment: Eu já tentei fazer isso, mas sempre que eu chamo o javascript, o tentativa volta ao valor original

Comment: `document.getElementById("adivinha_form").reset();`  isso está fazendo voce resetar o numero de tentativas pra 3 ... voce tem que colocar isso somente quando o cara acerta .. ou acabam as tentativas dele

Comment: continua dando erro

Answer (score 2):

```js
var chute;
var tentativa;
var numero;
var i=1;
function valida() {

    chute = parseInt(document.getElementById("chute").value)
    tentativa = parseInt(document.getElementById("tentativa").textContent)
    numero = parseInt(1 + Math.random() * 10)
    if(chute >= 0 && chute <= 10) {
        aleatorio(numero, chute)
    }
    else {
        alert("Favor digitar um numero de 0 a 10")
    }
}

function aleatorio(numero, chute) {
    if ((chute != numero)&&(tentativa > 0)) {
        
        alert("Você errou! Tente de novo")
        
        document.getElementById("chute").value = "";
        
         var x = document.getElementById("tentativa").textContent;
         document.getElementById("tentativa").innerHTML = x-i;
        
    }
    else if (tentativa == 0) {
        alert("Suas chances acabaram! O número correto é " + numero);
        document.getElementById("adivinha_form").reset();
        document.getElementById("tentativa").innerHTML = 3;
        document.getElementById("chute").value = "";
        chute="";
        numero="";
        i=1;
        
    }
    else if (chute == numero) {
        alert("Parabéns! Você acertou");
        document.getElementById("adivinha_form").reset();
        document.getElementById("tentativa").innerHTML = 3;
        document.getElementById("chute").value = "";
        chute="";
        numero="";
        i=1;
    }

}
```

```html
<form name="adivinha" id="adivinha_form" action="#" onsubmit="return false">
        <p>
            Seu chute: <br>
            <input type="text" id="chute" name="chute" value=""  autofocus>
        </p><br><br>

        <button onclick="valida()" reset="true">Arriscar</button>
        
        <p>Tentativas: <span id="tentativa">3</span> </p>
           
</form>
```